What to put as parameter for Widget constructor as follow: " check ????? "
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard(
      {@required this.colour = Colors.red, this.cardChild = ????????   });

  final Widget cardChild;
  final Color colour;
  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {return Container( child: cardChild, margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0), decoration: BoxDecoration( color: colour, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),); }

//*expecting to call that cardChild abstracting it into my main class*//


(Note :- if it not works please specify your flutter version)
There are two methods of resolving this error
First method :- make parameter requried
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard(
      {super.key,  required this.colour ,required this.cardChild }); <-- Like this

  final Widget cardChild;
  final Color colour;

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: cardChild,);
  }
}

Second method :- make Widget optional
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard(
      {super.key,  required this.colour ,this.cardChild });

  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Color colour;

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: cardChild,);
  }
}

